# Clients/Peers communication with wifi-direct on Android platform

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct

I have three Android devices: A,B,and C. They are connected via wifi-direct (assuming B is the group owner).

I just have two questions:
1. A want send a message to C, does the message have to pass the group owner B to reach C?
2. If the group owner B accidentally disconnected, will A still be able to send messages to C?

Thanks!

Comment: it has to go through b and if b disconnects you cant send msg

Comment: So the wifi-direct is not really a peer-to-peer connection?

Comment: its p2p itself but in your case a and c are connected 2 b only not directly

Comment: ok. so basically if a network contains more than 2 devices, all the communication must go through the group owner

Comment: @kan  if a network contains more than 2 devices, all the communication must go through the group owner?

is it true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Wifi direct communication the P2P group owner (P2P GO) device implements AP-like functionality in
the P2P Group., and devices acting as clients are known as P2P Clients. Hence all the communication has to go through the group owner channel.

And once the group owner disconnects, obviously the Routing channel has been killed and hence the group.
The clients have to restablish the connection and one of the client becomes the group owner.