# WIFI Direct - recreate group when owner disconnects

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I want to create an app for multiple clients chatting via WiFi direct.

The key feature I don't know how to do - when owner of a group disconnects, app should *transparently for the user* create a new group with a new owner and let all clients continue chatting.

I searched the web for the answer, but found only answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277030/clients-peers-communication-with-wifi-direct-on-android-platform/17334820#17334820). And now I comletely understand what I need to do, but absolutely not sure how to do it properly.

So, looking for a complete solution. Are there any tutorials (or, better, special libs for that?) that describe how to do it properly?

Comment: What you did and where you stucked? post the code creating issue for narrowing the question

Comment: I do not have a code yet :) I need to make estimations today about such an app as I described. And I made before only one-to-one connection example, so see that I can stuck with this "transparent group reconnection" feature.

Comment: So searching for any existing solutions

Comment: How can you search for a problem without having that?

Comment: Well, it's not a problem, it's a question - Are there any solutions, libraries etc. that simplify using of WiFi Direct's Group feature?

Comment: Basically there are no such libraries, so you would need to design it yourself. In general the acceptance dialog there will make the transparent re-connection rather hard to implement. Second issue would be simply designing which device would be the new group owner.

Comment: BTW, if your implementation would allow cutting off the normal WiFi, then you could use the CreateGroup way on creating an access point, that way your device could be GO for multiple clients and client for one GO at the same time, so you could create mesh type network between clients, so losing one GO would likely only effect few devices, which could then do reconnect to exiting network.